# Dynamic TSQL CASE and not display table not in comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Hey all I am doing a somewhat *dynamic* query and have an **CASE** in my select statements like so:

```
DECLARE @valueList varchar(8000)
DECLARE @pos int
DECLARE @len int
DECLARE @value varchar(8000)
SET @valueList = 'Description,hardwarePartNumber,poc,'

BEGIN
    SET @len = CHARINDEX(',', @valueList, @pos+1) - @pos
    SET @value = SUBSTRING(@valueList, @pos, @len)
SELECT 
    CAST(CASE WHEN @value = 'Description' THEN 
         BL.Description END AS varchar)                 AS 'Description',
    CAST(CASE WHEN @value = 'hardwarePartNumber' THEN 
         BL.hardwarePartNumber END AS varchar)          AS 'hardwarePartNumber',
    CAST(CASE WHEN @value = 'poc' THEN 
         UT.lastFirstMiddle END AS int)                 AS 'poc',
    CAST(CASE WHEN @value = 'quantity' THEN 
         BL.quantity END AS int)                        AS 'quantity',
      etc...etc....
FROM 
    bLine                  AS BL 
INNER JOIN usersTbl        AS UT 
    ON BL.poc              = UT.id
      etc...etc....
```

This works fine but places the table name(s) within the result even if it didn't have the table name in the **comma separated** list.

So for the example above the output would look like this:

```
Description    |hardwarePartNumber |poc        |quantity
--------------------------------------------------------
something here |568FHT             |Bob Barker |NULL
another thing  |GT43643            |Steve Jobs |NULL
Hey hey hey    |DSTN345            |Fat Albert |NULL
```

Notice how **quantity** is *NULL* because it was not found in the **comma separated** list. What I want it to look like is the following:

```
Description    |hardwarePartNumber |poc
-----------------------------------------------
something here |568FHT             |Bob Barker
another thing  |GT43643            |Steve Jobs
Hey hey hey    |DSTN345            |Fat Albert
```

So, if its not in the **comma separated** list then do not display the table in the final query.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to have an optional result column form a `select` statement – SQL just is not that kind of language. You could build the SQL as a string and then execute it (which does make maintenance harder), but you would probably be better just having your application run different SQL statements or choosing the columns in the application code. (You do seem to be suffering from the inner system effect – using a SQL engine to create your own SQL language.)

Comment: You could build your query dynamically, and use EXEC(@myDynamicQuery)

Comment: @Hooman Would you set an answer example to that using my query?

Comment: I would forget using a delimited list of values. Look into table valued parameters instead. They are a lot easier to deal with and they perform way faster too.

Comment: @StealthRT my suggestion was to build your dynamic query string in programming language. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Sadly it is not @Hooman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

SELECT CAST(BL.Description AS varchar) AS 'Description',
    CAST(  BL.hardwarePartNumber AS varchar)            AS 'hardwarePartNumber',
    CAST(UT.lastFirstMiddle END AS int)                 AS 'poc',
    CAST(BL.quantity END AS int)                        AS 'quantity',
      etc...etc....

INTO #Temp
FROM 
    bLine                  AS BL 
INNER JOIN usersTbl        AS UT 
    ON BL.poc              = UT.id
      etc...etc....

DECLARE @valueList varchar(8000)
SET @valueList = 'Description,hardwarePartNumber,poc,'

DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = 'SELECT ' + LEFT(@valuelist,LEN(@valuelist)-1 + ' FROM #Temp'    
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the etc. style - Use CROSS APPLY and STRING_SPLIT:

```
Select distinct
    ..
    compare BL columns against BL2.value
    ..

FROM 
    bomLine                AS BL 
    cross apply STRING_SPLIT ('Description,hardwarePartNumber,poc,', ',') BL2
```

Comment: **Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.**

Comment: @StealthRT You are using SQL Server 2016? An you check the version settings?

Comment: Sorry, its version 2014.

Comment: Should be fine. Maybe it is restricted to a lower version? Check in dB properties > options for the compatibility version.